# Position Fixed in Chrome

Tags: css, safari, webkit, google-chrome

I have a little problem with my site, I have a bar and on it a box that float above the bar, everything works fine in IE, Firefox, Opera, but in Chrome and Safari the box that must be above the bar float by the bar side no above it.

```
 #barraDerecha 
 {
     width:240px;
     background-color:#e5e5e5;
     border-left:solid 2px #CCC;
     border-bottom:solid 2px #CCC;
     position:absolute; 
     margin-top:-10px;
     margin-left:717px;
     height:auto;
 }

 #barraDerecha #menu
 {
    display:block; 
    position:fixed;
    width:220px;
 }
```

**barraDerecha** is the container and **menu** is the box that goes above the container

Can somebody help me please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see a difference in Opera, Firefox or Chrome. However, no elements appear to be fixed position in any browser.

Comment: You have to a plan to see the right bar

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone is getting the same chrome behaviour.

It looks like chrome considers that the viewport of an element added to the DOM after the page is loaded (for instance, using jQuery.load()) is restricted to the containing div of this element.

I guess .asp is injecting your barraDerecha after document load, so it positions relative to its container.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for u answer Thor you can see the example in [www.autos.ultimahora.com/altaanuncio.html](http://www.autos.ultimahora.com/altaanuncio.html)

I can't put fixed to #barraderecha cause in that way my bar move with the menu

Here is who I use the class:

```
<div id="barraDerecha" > 
<div id="barraRight" runat="server">
    <div style="padding:10px;" id="menu" >
        <div class="titulosAzules15">
         <center>
         <asp:Label ID="lblUsted" runat="server" Text="USTED ELIGÍO EL PLAN"></asp:Label>
             <br />
             <br />
         <asp:Image ID="imgPlan" runat="server" />
         <br />
         <asp:Label ID="lblPrecio" CssClass="DestaquesBordo14" runat="server"></asp:Label>
             <br />
         </center>

         </div>


    </div>     
</div>    
</div>
```

**You have to select a plan and then push on Siguiente button**

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me, but isn't #menu within #barraDerecha?

If so, it would only be natural that it would be fixed within #barraDerecha unless you specify the position furthermore.

```
#barraDecha {
   position:fixed; top:0; left:0; }
```

A better description (perhaps a visual) would help i terms of describing the problem more accurately.

Comment: According to standard, position fixed is always relative to the viewport, not to any parent.